# Mapping AbstractEntity to SubClassDTO - Single Table Strategy

Tags: java, spring, jpa, mapping, abstract

I'm trying to mapp Entity (TrainingEntity) to DTO, where one of the fields is a Set with ManyToMany reference to an AbstractEntity (CoachEntity) divided by Single Table into two subclasses: ExternalCoach and InternalCoach.

Both subclasses have different data, therefore require two different mappers.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRAINING")
public class TrainingEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name = "TRAINING_EMPLOYEE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "TRAINING_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "COACH_ID") })
    private Set<CoachEntity> coachEntities;

@Column(nullable = false)
private TrainingType trainingType;

......some data....

}
```

Abstract Coach Entity

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "COACH")
    @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
    public abstract class CoachEntity extends AbstractEntity {

 ......some data....

}
```

Coach Subclasses:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("EXTERNAL")
public class ExternalCoachEntity extends CoachEntity {
 ......some data....
}



@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("INTERNAL")
public class InternalCoachEntity extends CoachEntity {
 ......some data....
    }
```

One mapper for Abstract Coach class won't have acces to subclasses methods and fields, so I need two different for External and Internal. Than I would have to use them in TrainingMapper class, but (example of internal):

```
public class CustomTrainingMapper {

    public static TrainingDto toTrainingDto(TrainingEntity trainingEntity){
        if(trainingEntity == null){
            return null;
        }

        if(trainingEntity.getTrainingType().equals(TrainingType.INTERNAL)){
            Set<CoachEntity> coachEntities = trainingEntity.getCoachEntities();


            Set<CoachDto> coachDtos = CustomInternalCoachMapper.toDTOSet((Set<InternalCoachEntity>)coachEntities);
        }
```

I get:

```
  cannot cast from Set<CoachEntity> to Set<InternalCoachEntity>
```

Without cast it simply doesn't see mappers methods with subclass input.

```
The method toDTOSet(Set<InternalCoachEntity>) in the type CustomInternalCoachMapper is not applicable for the arguments (Set<CoachEntity>)
```

When in mapper I change method input to abstract Coach Class it doesn't see subclasses methods and fields.

Part of InternalMapper:

```
public class CustomInternalCoachMapper {

    public static CoachDto toCoachDto(InternalCoachEntity coachEntity) {
        if (coachEntity == null) {
            return null;
        }

        EmployeeDto employeeDto = CustomEmployeeMapper.toEmployeeDto(coachEntity.getEmployeeEntity());

        return new InternalCoachDto(coachEntity.getId(), coachEntity.getVersion(), coachEntity.getCreateDate(),
                coachEntity.getUpdateDate(), coachEntity.getName(), coachEntity.getSurname(), employeeDto);
    }
```

[image]

Is it possible to mapp this AbstractEntity Set into subclasses DTOs?
I also tried with AbstractDto for Coaches, but then I'm facing the same problem with no access to subclasses getters and setters.